# Modify internal structure when implementing std::hash<T>

Tags: c++, c++11, hash, constants, unordered-set

I'm writing a custom `OrderedTree` class I want to use as a key to an `unordered_set`.

I want to do a couple things when hashing the Tree:

1. calculate the hash lazily and cache it as needed (since this may be an expensive operation),
2. maybe balance the tree.

Neither of these operations change the semantic equality or hash value of the object, but they do modify some private fields.

Unfortunately, trying to modify any members in `OrderedTree` while inside `std::hash<Tree>::operator()` seems to violate const correctness that `unordered_set` expects.

Can I use my `OrderedTree` with `unordered_set`? If so, how?

EDIT:

As per request in the comments, minimal proof of concept:

```
#include <unordered_set>

std::size_t hash_combine(std::size_t a, std::size_t b) {
  // TODO: Copy from boost source or something
  return 0;
}

struct Node {
  int value;
  Node *left, *right, *parent;

  std::size_t hash(std::size_t seed) const {
    if (left != nullptr)
      seed = left->hash(seed);
    std::hash<int> hasher;
    seed = hash_combine(seed, hasher(value));
    if (right != nullptr)
      seed = right->hash(seed);
    return seed;
  }
};

struct Tree {

  Tree(): hash_(0), root(nullptr) {}

  Node *root;

  std::size_t hash() const {
    if (hash_ == 0 && root != nullptr) {
      hash_ = root->hash(7);
    }
    return hash_;
  }

private:
  std::size_t hash_;
};

namespace std {
  template<>
  struct hash<Tree> {
    std::size_t operator()(const Tree& t) const {
      return t.hash();
    }
  };
}

int main() {
  std::unordered_set<Tree> set;
}
```

When I try to compile I get:

```
Sample.cc:31:13: error: cannot assign to non-static data member within const member function 'hash'
      hash_ = root->hash(7);
      ~~~~~ ^
Sample.cc:29:15: note: member function 'Tree::hash' is declared const here
  std::size_t hash() const {
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: How does "seems to violate const correctness" manifest itself? Is this just some general angst, or do you not know how to implement it, or do you get compiler errors?

Comment: Ever heard of the keyword 'mutable'?

Comment: @JVApen I hadn't before. Thank you! That seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. If you post an answer with it, I'll accept it.

Comment: @PeteBecker It was all in my head when I posted the question, but I'll try to whip up a proof of concept in a min or two

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a guarantee that std containers will only call `const` members when doing `const` or logically `const` operations.  If those `const` operations are multiple-reader safe, then so is the container; contrawise, if they are not, neither is the container.

The immutability of the hash value and equality (or `<` on ordered containers) are the *only* things you need guarantee in a key type in an associative container.  Actual `const` gives the above multiple-reader guarantee, which can be quite useful.  What more, violating it costs you using this in the future, and/or subtle buts when someone does presume `const` means immutable.

You could carefully synchonize the write operation internally to keep the multiple-reader guarantee, or you can give it up.

To violate `const`, typically you use `mutable`.  A `const` method that uses casting to bypass `const` risks Undefined Behaviour if the object was *actually* `const`, and not just a `const` view of a non-`const` object.

In general, be careful before using this kind of optimizaton; it can easily increase code complexity (hance bugs, maintenance, etc) more than it adds speed.  And speeding up code is fungible: make sure you identify this as *slow* code and this part as a bottlenecm prior to investing in it.  And if you are going to balance in hash, *why wait for hash*?  Balance before insert!

Comment: When you say 'A const method that uses casting to bypass...', you mean `const_cast` right? A program with `mutable` still behaves well? I agree with your attitude about `const`, and I'm not sure I will actually use `mutable`, but I want to learn more about dangerous features so I can use them if it turns out I really need to.

Comment: @math `const_cast` or equivalent C-style cast, yes.  Violating `const` on something declared `const` (and not just a `const&` to a non-`const`) is UB.  `mutable` members do not violate `const` in this sense, even if modified in a `const` method.